Vocabulaire incertain ou très rare : « paysannasse »
Je me rappelle d'un terme qui dans la bouche de toutes les personnes qui l'ont prononcé devant moi, se doit d'être péjoratif, très péjoratif ; je ne l'ai jamais trouvé dans mes lectures. C'est « paysannasse », qui ne figure dans les dictionnaires que comme la troisième personne du verbe « paysanner » du subjonctif imparfait (Wiktionnaire), lequel n'offre aucun problème puisque il a une entrée dans le TLFi, bien qu'un hapax.

(TLFi) Paysanner, verbe, hapax. Vivre à la manière des paysans.

Le verbe lui-même n'a rien de péjoratif, mais je n'ai aucun doute qu'il n'en est pas de même pour le nom. De plus, il est  évident que la terminaison « -asse » est le suffixe péjoratif « -asse » .


Péjorative
a) Subst. (animé ou coll. de l'animé) :
canasse « gens de bas étage »
crapouillasse « grande crapule »
fillasse « mauvaise fille »
pédantasse « mauvais pédant »
populace « peuple » (avec mépris)
pouillasse « grand pouilleux »
savantasse « pédant qui joue les savants »


Comme je ne sait pas d'où sort ce mot, la question  suivante se pose.
Saurait-on si ce terme reflète un usage quelconque (suffisamment important, régional ou autre, citadin, par exemple) ou si plutôt il s'agirait  d'une conséquence de la productivité du suffixe « -asse » limitée à une section de la population  très négligeable ?

(TLFi) productivité 4. LING. Action de produire de nouvelles expressions nominales, adjectivales et autres, expressions qui ne se sont pas encore rencontrées dans les phrases réalisées (d'apr. Ling. 1972).


Le sens du mot est bien celui que tu décris, un dérivé péjoratif de paysan. Sa formation est régulière. Il a donc pu apparaître indépendamment à plusieurs endroits et périodes.
Il est très rare mais on le trouve quand même dans quelques ouvrages:

Se débarrassant du bourgeron et du chapeau, elle glisse les mains sous son tablier de paysannasse, dont elle tire un petit pantalon brodé et le mantelet assorti.
Jacques Audiberti, La fourmi dans le corps, 1961.


— Tout ça, c'est bien joli, rétorquait ma mère, que ces considérations laissaient froide, mais de quoi vivrais-tu ? Tu veux devenir un paysannasse, comme tonton Camille ?
Jean Carrière, Le nez dans l'herbe, 1981.


— C’est tout juste le contraire. Tu es trop bien, tu es une dame, et moi je ne suis qu’un paysannasse, ce n’est pas possible.
Claude Courchay, Avril est un mois cruel : roman, 1987.

L'action des citations se situe dans le sud de la France et leurs auteurs en sont natifs ou familiers, on peut donc penser qu'il y a un lien avec le substrat occitan qui utilise couramment le suffixe -asse (oc: -assa).
Le Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch donne, page 471, dans l'entrée pagensis (paysan) le mot pésanasse attesté en Charente avec comme définition homme grossier associé au provençal peisanas.
On retrouve ce mot dans le texte suivant, en provençal mistralien:

Peire Simoun, Lou Brusc, 1881.

Ceci se passait au début de l'invention du chemin de fer: un brave paysannasse de Vitrolles, un dimanche matin, s'était mis en tête d'aller faire un tour, en train, jusqu'à Marseille.

Ici, peisanas n'est pas utilisé trop péjorativement. Sa présence dans un texte relativement récent renforce l'idée d'une origine provençale/occitane du mot.
